# Genymotion Struck in black screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

My Genymotion strucks in the black screen as shown below [image: Genymotion balck scren].When I restart my MAC, the genymotion starts and works perfectly but it quits automatically (after an hour). When I try to start the Genymotion from Virtual box I get the error "cannotfind 'system/bin/install-recovery.sh' disabling 'flash_recovery;". Please see SS below for error from Virtual Box. Thanks in Advance !!
[image]

Comment: maybe try checkout out this answer, is for a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547907/genymotion-stays-on-black-screen-when-loading-emulator/39547908#39547908

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem was because of connecting to VPN.If I disconnect from VPN things work perfect. Posting it here so that it may be useful to someone else. Thanks !!